# Neo4J 2.0.2 + Gremlin plugin: the console doesn't run

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

I'm experimenting with Neo4J + Gremlin plugin, unfortunately I got this error (bellow) when I try to use the Gremlin console web (the console didn't runs on Gremlin language):

```
    SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/server/logging/Logger
        at org.neo4j.server.webadmin.console.GremlinSession.<clinit>(GremlinSession.java:42)
        at org.neo4j.server.webadmin.console.GremlinSessionCreator.newSession(GremlinSessionCreator.java:35)
    ......
```

Any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: I solved it. Neo4J 2.0.2 server has changed the Logger class, so I modified `GremlinSession.java` code in order to use `java.util.logging.Logger` class instead of `org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger`. Finally the Gremlin console web works fine:

Comment: I'm pleased you managed to solve it on your own. Please change your comment to an answer and accept it. That way you can help someone else who has the same problem

Comment: Also if you issue a pull request against the repository, we can accept that and every will benefit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4J 2.0.2 server has changed the Logger class, so I modified `GremlinSession.java` code in order to use `java.util.logging.Logger` class instead of `org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger`. Finally the Gremlin console web works fine:

Here you will find the new `GremlinSession.java` code.

```
            /**
             * Copyright (c) 2002-2014 "Neo Technology,"
             * Network Engine for Objects in Lund AB [http://neotechnology.com]
             *
             * This file is part of Neo4j.
             *
             * Neo4j is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
             * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
             * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
             * (at your option) any later version.
             *
             * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
             * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
             * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
             * GNU General Public License for more details.
             *
             * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
             * along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
             */
            package org.neo4j.server.webadmin.console;

            import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.TransactionalGraph;
            import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j2.Neo4j2Graph;
            import groovy.lang.Binding;
            import groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException;
            import org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.IO;
            import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
            import org.neo4j.helpers.Pair;
            import org.neo4j.server.database.Database;

            import java.util.logging.Logger;
            import java.util.logging.Level;
            import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
            import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
            import java.io.PrintStream;
            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.HashMap;
            import java.util.List;
            import java.util.Map;

            public class GremlinSession implements ScriptSession {
                    private static final String INIT_FUNCTION = "init()";
                    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(GremlinSession.class.getName());
                    private final Database database;
                    private final IO io;
                    private final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    private final List<String> initialBindings;
                    protected GremlinWebConsole scriptEngine;

                    public GremlinSession(Database database) {
                            this.database = database;
                            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(baos));

                            io = new IO(System.in, out, out);

                            Map<String, Object> bindings = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                            bindings.put("g", getGremlinWrappedGraph());
                            bindings.put("out", out);

                            initialBindings = new ArrayList<String>(bindings.keySet());

                            try {
                                scriptEngine = new GremlinWebConsole(new Binding(bindings), io);
                            } catch (final Exception failure) {
                                scriptEngine = new GremlinWebConsole() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void execute(String script) {
                                        io.out.println("Could not start Groovy during Gremlin initialization, reason:");
                                        failure.printStackTrace(io.out);
                                    }
                                };
                            }
                    }

                    /**
                     * Take some gremlin script, evaluate it in the context of this gremlin
                     * session, and return the result.
                     *
                     * @param script
                     * @return the return string of the evaluation result, or the exception
                     *         message.
                     */
                    @Override
                    public Pair<String, String> evaluate(String script) {
                            String result = null;
                            try (Transaction tx = database.getGraph().beginTx()) {
                                if (script.equals(INIT_FUNCTION)) {
                                    result = init();
                                } else {
                                    try {
                                        scriptEngine.execute(script);
                                        result = baos.toString();
                                    } finally {
                                        resetIO();
                                    }
                                }
                                tx.success();
                            } catch (GroovyRuntimeException ex) {
                                log.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.toString());
                                result = ex.getMessage();
                            }
                            return Pair.of(result, null);
                    }

                    private String init() {
                            StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
                            out.append("\n");
                            out.append("         \\,,,/\n");
                            out.append("         (o o)\n");
                            out.append("-----oOOo-(_)-oOOo-----\n");
                            out.append("\n");

                            out.append("Available variables:\n");
                            for (String variable : initialBindings) {
                                out.append("  " + variable + "\t= ");
                                out.append(evaluate(variable));
                            }
                            out.append("\n");

                            return out.toString();
                    }

                    private void resetIO() {
                            baos.reset();
                    }

                    private TransactionalGraph getGremlinWrappedGraph() {
                            Neo4j2Graph neo4jGraph = null;
                            try {
                                neo4jGraph = new Neo4j2Graph(database.getGraph());
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                            return neo4jGraph;
                    }
            }
```